# MKMapView's delegate is not called

Tags: ios, delegates, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkmapviewdelegate

I have an `UIViewController` class to manage an `MKMapView` defined like this:

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
```

Within the implementation of this view controller, I have:

```
- (void)loadView
{
   MKMapView *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200)];
   mapView.delegate = self;
   self.view = mapView;
}


- (void)centerMapInLoc:(CLLocation *)loc
{
   CustomAnnotation *annotation = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinates:loc.coordinate title:@"My position" subTitle:nil];

   [(MKMapView *)self.view addAnnotation:annotation];
}


- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
   MKAnnotationView *v = nil;

   // Custom logic

   v.annotation = annotation;
   return v;
}
```

Being `centerMapInLoc:` a public method I call from another view controller. The annotation is created within such method, but `viewForAnnotation:` delegate method is not called when the annotation is added. I don't understand why, since the delegate is set in `loadView` method.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you viewing in the map the coordinates of the annotation??, `viewForAnnotation` will only execute if the annotation is going to appear on the map. Move to the portion of the map that should show the annotation and verify that the method is being called

Comment: @gabuh Yes, I'm displaying the appropriate region, in fact if I add the annotation within `viewDidLoad` method, the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method is called and annotation displayed...

Comment: And are you sure that self.view is initialized when you are calling  centerMapInLoc from the other viewController? NSLog self.view in centerMapInLoc.

Comment: @gabuh Yes, it is... and delegate seems to be different from nil as well...

Comment: try adding the mapView as child of the main view in your viewController, instead of replacing it. `[self.view addSubview:mapView]` you can keep a reference to the mapView in your viewController (add a MKMapView property) to help you add the annotation in centerMapInLoc